How to evaluate This Series :$\dfrac{x}{1+x}+\dfrac{2x^2}{1+x^2}+\dfrac{4x^4}{1+x^4}+\cdots$
How to evaluate This Series :$$S=\dfrac{x}{1+x}+\dfrac{2x^2}{1+x^2}+\dfrac{4x^4}{1+x^4}+\cdots$$
therfore:
$$S=\dfrac{x}{1+x}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2kx^{2k}}{1+x^{2k}}$$
This series Converges if $x^2<1$
It's my first time encountering this type of series, is there a way to calculate this

Are you sure it isn't suppose to be $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^kx^{2^k}}{1+x^{2^k}}?$$

If you expand each term in a geometric series, and add term-by-term, do you just get $x+x^2+x^3+\dotsb=x/(1-x)$?

I'm not sure about that, I found this problem in this book summation and series by L. B. W. JOLLEY, M.A. (cantab.), M.I.E.E.

Well, my formula matches the first term, and it would be weird to offer three terms of only two matched the pattern.

I have that book! What page? Never mind: series 88 on page 18, where it says it equals $x/(1-x)$, and tells you where to find it in the literature.

That doesn't mean my answer is right, only that this sort of expression for an infinite series is rife for miscommunication - we can only guess the meaning.

Page 18. Problem No. 88

The reference is to E. P. Adams, Smithsonian Mathematical Formulae, page 118. Maybe you should look for that, see whether it gives a proof (but I'd suggest that what I outlined in my first comment is the way to go).

I searched through the references provided by the author, but I did not find proof of this

Yeah, I get, with  my formulation, when $n=2^kq$ for $q$ odd that the coefficient for $x^n$ will be $2^k-(1+2+4+8+\cdots +2^{k-1})=1,$ so I likewise get $\frac{x}{1-x}.$

You downloaded the book, from https://repository.si.edu/handle/10088/23627 ? By the way, for future reference, when you post a question here, you ought to supply all the information you know about it. You should have told us the book it came from, the page, the reference it gave, and that you had already looked at the reference. It's a courtesy, so the people you are asking for help don't go wasting their time, and yours, telling you things you already know.

The Smithsonian book gives a 4th term to the series, $8x^8/(1+x^8)$, so, @Thomas, you and I have the right series. $2^k$, not $2k$. The book, a few pages earlier, talks about reordering terms in an absolutely convergent series, so I'm sure we also have the intended method of verifying the answer.

@Mostafa you can also read my answer, where I use telescoping: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1916692/190421
